# The data don't load after login meteor

Tags: javascript, authentication, load, meteor

I have a login page in my Meteor app. I have customized my login :

```
{{#if isLogged}}
    {{>index}}
{{else}}
    {{>login}}
{{/if}}
```

If the user is logged I load "index" template.

So I log a user with success and the app route me on the "index" but no collections was loaded.

For example I have :

```
Template.listWorkspace.rendered = function () {
           //some stuff
    });
```

This is not laod when I'm logging. I must press F5 button for load all my data.

EDIT

Here is the isLogged declaration :

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
Template.indexLogin.helpers({
    isLogged : function () {
        var indexIsLoggedUser = Meteor.user();
        return indexIsLoggedUser != null;
    }
});
```

}

Here is the index template declaration :

```
 <template name="index">
{{>widgetWorkspace}}
 </template>

<template name="widgetWorkspace">
{{>header}} 
    {{>workspace}}
</template>

 <template name="workspace">
<div class="row">
    <!-- <button class="btn btn-default" id="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add widget</button> -->
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="editmode" data-i18n="btn.editMode"></button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-i18n="btn.addWidgets"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>{{>bootstrapModal}}

    <!-- <button class="btn btn-danger" id="addContainer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add Container</button> -->
    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" id="serialize">Serialize</button>-->
</div>
<br>
<div id="widgetMainContainer">
    {{#each Widgets}}
        {{>widget}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
 </template>
```

EDIT2 :

This is the template with the workspace of users :

```
 <template name="listWorkspace">
 <ul id="workspaces"></ul>
 </template>
```

This is the rendered some javascript code :

```
Template.listWorkspace.rendered = function () {
    var headerWorkspaceUserLogged = Meteor.users.find({_id: Session.get('user_id')}).fetch();
    var headerWorkspaces = headerWorkspaceUserLogged[0].workspace;

    if(headerWorkspaces == null || headerWorkspaces == undefined) {
        console.log('empty');
    }

    async.forEachSeries(headerWorkspaces, function(item, callback) {
        var d = $('<li/>');
        d.attr('rel', item.id-1).addClass('workspace-mini').click(function() {
            NProgress.start();
            $('#workspaces li').removeClass('workspaceSelected');
            $(this).addClass('workspaceSelected');
            var text = $('<div/>'); 
            text.addClass('workspaceText')
                    .text('workspace ' + (parseInt($(this).attr('rel'))+1))
                    .appendTo($(this))
                    .position({ my: 'center center', at: 'center center', of: $(window)})
                    .fadeIn(function() { $(this).fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove; })});
            current_workspace = headerWorkspaces[parseInt($(this).attr('rel'))];
            current_workspace_number = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
            Session.set('current_workspace_number', current_workspace_number+1);
            Session.set('current_workspace', current_workspace);
            //on selectionne le workspace dans la base Mongo en fonction du workspace selectionné
            Meteor.call('updateIdSelectdWorkspace', Session.get('user_id'), Session.get('current_workspace').name);
            NProgress.done();
        });
        $('#workspaces').append(d);

        //Pour l'ajout d'un nouveau workspace on memorise l'id du dernier workspace
        Session.set('i', item.id); 

        callback();
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('done');
    });
    $('#workspaces').append('<div id="addWorkspace"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></div>');
    $('#addWorkspace').css('float', 'right')
        .css('margin-left', '5px')
        .css('margin-top', '2px')
        .css('cursor', 'pointer');
};
```

The Template.listWorkspace.rendered = function () doesn't load the first time when I log into the app.

Someone can explain me the order of loading with meteor ? :)

Comment: Can we see how `isLogged`, `index` and `login` are declared? My hunch is that `isLogged` is not reactive, thus changing it doesn't rerun the template.

Comment: Do you have `header` template defined as well?

Comment: Yes my header load data from collection too, and when I'm logging data don't appear :(

Comment: What do you mean by "no collections was loaded"? I see no collections in the code. I don't see a `listWorkspace` template as well. We won't know how your code runs until all pieces if it are up for investigation.

Comment: See I had edit my post with most details :). The template.listWorkspace.rendered = function ()... don't load the first time when I'm logging into the app

Answer (score 0):

There are many things amiss here. First off, you don't need your own helper to check if the user is logged in. Per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_currentuser), just use Meteor's recommended `{{#if currentUser}}`.

Secondly, you have a templating system at your disposal. Why don't you use that to define how the widgets should appear on the page, rather than programmatically inserting DOM nodes in your `rendered` function? And why are you using `async`? Try to do everything possible via templates, as few as possible, before dropping into helpers only to achieve what templates can't. You also generally don't need to dive into callbacks and asynchronous code in Meteor.

Comment: Yes you alright, and now I use currentUser and I delete the async loop, but my problem is always the same. When I log my user the loginWithPassword don't work and the logginIn method stay fix.

I must edit my code for reload the page...

Comment: There's no page reloading in Meteor. `{{#unless currentUser}} {{> yourLoginTemplate}} {{else}} {{> yourHomePageTemplate}} {{/unless}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting your project with meteor reset command i had similar problem after renaming file and now works for me with `{{#if currentUser}}` helper.